# Java HTTPS Client wit Secure Socket

Tags: java, ssl

I am currently writing a Framework with some Network and reflection utils.

As an example for my Network Class, I like to write an HTTP/S Client.

Currently, the Server is accepting the Client Handshake, but if I send an HTTP Header the Server don't answer.

I tried to Debug with some Javax SSL Extension Properties, but it seems okay for me.

Headers (Working on normal HTTP):

> ```
> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.xxx.de
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
> Accept-Language: en-u
> ```

The Server is receiving the Request, but the Java Part didn't recognise the Response...

[image]

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:D:\JetBrains\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\213.5281.15\lib\idea_rt.jar=1044:D:\JetBrains\apps\IDEA-U\ch-1\213.5281.15\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre\lib\rt.jar;F:\Programmieren\MyTrioX\ProxMox\target\classes;F:\Programmieren\MyTrioX\Extra\target\classes;F:\Programmieren\MyTrioX\Slave\target\classes" de.bytestore.mytriox.proxmox.ProxMox
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:41.072 CET|SSLCipher.java:438|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
BBB
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.543 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.544 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS12
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.550 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.550 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.550 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.550 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.551 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.552 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.553 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.553 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.553 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.553 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.553 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS11
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.554 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.554 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.554 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.554 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.554 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.555 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.556 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.556 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.556 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.556 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.556 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.557 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.557 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.557 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.557 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.557 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.558 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.558 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLS10
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.559 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.560 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.561 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.562 CET|HandshakeContext.java:297|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for SSL30
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.708 CET|SSLCipher.java:1817|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.710 CET|SSLCipher.java:1971|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.769 CET|SSLCipher.java:1817|KeyLimit read side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|FINE|01|main|2021-11-02 19:29:42.773 CET|SSLCipher.java:1971|KeyLimit write side: algorithm = AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE
countdown value = 137438953472
[SUCCESS]: Handshake with Server 173.212.219.135 via Method TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 was correct.
[INFO]: Starting Client Socket connecting to Address 173.212.219.135 on Port 443.
[SUCCESS]: Client connected to Address www.byte-store.de/173.212.219.135 on Port 443.
WRITE
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.byte-store.de
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Accept-Language: en-us
```

ClientSocket.class:

```
package de.bytestore.mytriox.network.client;


public class ClientSocket {
    private ArrayList<ClientInterface> listenerIO = new ArrayList<ClientInterface>();

    private InetSocketAddress networkIO;
    private Socket socketIO;

    private int timeoutIO = 0;
    private Thread threadIO;
    private Timer timerIO;

    // Define Secure Settings of Socket.
    private boolean secureIO = false;

    private CertificateUtils certificateIO = new CertificateUtils();

    private boolean binaryIO = false;
    private boolean stringIO = false;

    // Store Client Callbacks for String as Initiator.
    private HashMap<String, ClientCallback> callbacksIO = new HashMap<String, ClientCallback>();

    private OutputStream outputIO = null;

    public ClientSocket(InetSocketAddress networkIO) {
        this.networkIO = networkIO;
    }

    public ClientSocket(String addressIO, int portIO) {
        this.networkIO = new InetSocketAddress(addressIO, portIO);
    }


    public void setBinary(boolean binaryIO) {
        this.binaryIO = binaryIO;
    }

    public void setString(boolean stringIO) {
        this.stringIO = stringIO;
    }

    public void setSecure(boolean stateIO) {
        this.secureIO = stateIO;
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return secureIO;
    }

    /**
     * Set Timeout of Socket in Seconds.
     *
     * @param timeoutIO
     */
    public void setTimeout(int timeoutIO) {
        this.timeoutIO = timeoutIO * 1000;
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {

            if (secureIO) {
                this.certificateIO = new CertificateUtils("TLS", "JKS", "12345678", new FileManager("F:\\Programmieren\\MyTrioX\\MyTrioX-CONTROLLER\\database\\keystore.jks"), new FileManager("F:\\Programmieren\\MyTrioX\\MyTrioX-CONTROLLER\\database\\store.jks"));


                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "F:\\Programmieren\\MyTrioX\\MyTrioX-CONTROLLER\\configuration\\trust.store");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "12345678");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl # very verbose debug");

                SSLSocketFactory factoryIO = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
                //this.certificateIO.getSocketFactory();

                System.out.println("BBB");

                // Create SecureSocket via Factory.
                this.socketIO = factoryIO.createSocket(this.networkIO.getAddress(), 443);

                // Print Message if Client Handshake was correct.
                ((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent handshakeIO) {
                        logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.SUCCESS, "Handshake with Server " + socketIO.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " via Method " + handshakeIO.getCipherSuite() + " was correct.");
                    }
                });

                ((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).setEnabledCipherSuites(((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).getSupportedCipherSuites());
                ((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).setEnabledProtocols(((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).getSupportedProtocols());
                ((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).startHandshake();

                SSLParameters parametersIO = new SSLParameters();
                parametersIO.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");

                ((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).setSSLParameters(parametersIO);

                //SSLEngine engineIO = certificateIO.getEngine();
                //SSLContext contextIO = certificateIO.getContext();

                //logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Server " + (((SSLSocket) this.socketIO).getNeedClientAuth() ? "need" : "don't need") + " Client Authentication.");
                //logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Found " + Arrays.toString(engineIO.getSupportedCipherSuites()) + " Supported Cipher Suites for Server Socket.");


                if (CacheHandler.debugIO) {
                    //CertificateUtils.printInfo((SSLSocket) this.socketIO);
                }
            } else this.socketIO = new Socket(this.networkIO.getAddress(), this.networkIO.getPort());

            logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Starting Client Socket connecting to Address " + this.networkIO.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on Port " + this.networkIO.getPort() + ".");

            socketIO.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            socketIO.setKeepAlive(true);
            socketIO.setSoTimeout(timeoutIO);

            logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.SUCCESS, "Client connected to Address " + networkIO.getAddress() + " on Port " + networkIO.getPort() + ".");

            connected(socketIO);

            // Open Output Stream of Socket.
            this.outputIO = socketIO.getOutputStream();

            // Open Input Stream of Socket.
            InputStream inputIO = socketIO.getInputStream();

            this.threadIO = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //while (!socketIO.isClosed() && readerIO.read() != -1) {
                        while (/**!shutdownIO &&**/socketIO.isConnected() && !socketIO.isClosed()) {

                            // Byte Buffer ho contains read Data.
                            byte[] bufferIO = new byte[inputIO.available()];

                            // Read Data into Buffer and store (EOF).
                            int codeIO = inputIO.read(bufferIO);

                            //if (bufferIO.length != 0 && inputIO.available() == 0) {
                            if (bufferIO.length != 0 && inputIO.available() == 0) {

                                if (binaryIO)
                                    binary(socketIO, bufferIO);

                                if (stringIO)
                                    string(socketIO, new String(bufferIO, charsetIO));

                                if (hasCallbacks()) {
                                    String dataIO = new String(bufferIO);

                                    for (String keyIO : callbacksIO.keySet()) {
                                        if (dataIO.contains(keyIO)) {

                                            logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Executing Callback for Initiator '" + keyIO + "'.");

                                            callbacksIO.get(keyIO).string(socketIO, dataIO);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // Sleep for 100 Milliseconds (CPU Usage)
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }

                        inputIO.reset();
                        inputIO.close();

                        if (!socketIO.isClosed()) {
                            socketIO.close();
                        }

                        disconnected(socketIO);

                        threadIO.stop();
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException errorIO) {
                        if (errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Stream closed.") || errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Connection reset")) {
                            logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Client was disconnected from Server with Address " + networkIO.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on Port " + networkIO.getPort() + ".");

                            disconnected(socketIO);
                        } else logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Socket throw an Error ", errorIO);
                    }
                }
            });

            this.threadIO.start();

        } catch (IOException errorIO) {
            logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Error by connecting to Socket on Port " + this.networkIO.getPort() + ".", errorIO);
        }

    }


    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            this.outputIO.close();

            if (!this.socketIO.isClosed()) {
                this.socketIO.close();
            }

            this.threadIO.stop();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void connected(Socket clientIO) {
        for (ClientInterface interfaceIO : listenerIO) {
            interfaceIO.connected(clientIO);
        }
    }

    public void disconnected(Socket clientIO) {
        for (ClientInterface interfaceIO : listenerIO) {
            interfaceIO.disconnected(clientIO);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call ClientInterfaces with String Method.
     *
     * @param clientIO
     * @param dataIO
     */
    protected void string(Socket clientIO, String dataIO) {
        for (ClientInterface interfaceIO : listenerIO) {
            interfaceIO.string(clientIO, dataIO);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call ClientInterfaces with Binary Method.
     *
     * @param clientIO
     * @param binaryIO
     */
    protected void binary(Socket clientIO, byte[] binaryIO) {
        for (ClientInterface interfaceIO : this.listenerIO) {
            interfaceIO.binary(clientIO, binaryIO);
        }
    }


    public void registerListener(ClientInterface clientIO) {
        this.listenerIO.add(clientIO);
    }

    public void unregisterListener(ClientInterface clientIO) {
        this.listenerIO.remove(clientIO);
    }

    public void unregisterListeners() {
        this.listenerIO = new ArrayList<ClientInterface>();
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        if (this.socketIO != null) {
            return (!this.socketIO.isClosed() && this.socketIO.isConnected());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socketIO;
    }

    public boolean hasCallbacks() {
        return !(this.callbacksIO.isEmpty());
    }

    public boolean hasCallback(String initiatorIO) {
        return this.callbacksIO.containsKey(initiatorIO);
    }

    public ClientCallbackInterface addCallback(String initiatorIO, ClientCallback callbackIO) {
        this.callbacksIO.put(initiatorIO, callbackIO);

        logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Added Callback with Initiator '" + initiatorIO + "' to callbacks.");

        return callbackIO;
    }

    public void removeCallback(String initiatorIO) {
        this.callbacksIO.remove(initiatorIO);
    }


    protected HashMap<String, ClientCallback> getCallbacks() {
        return this.callbacksIO;
    }

    public InetSocketAddress getNetwork() {
        return this.networkIO;
    }

    public void setNetwork(InetSocketAddress networkIO) {
        this.networkIO = networkIO;
    }

    public void write(String dataIO) {
        this.write(dataIO.getBytes(charsetIO));
    }

    public void write(byte[] dataIO) {
        try {
            this.outputIO.write(dataIO);
        } catch (IOException exceptionIO) {
            logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Can't write to Server.", exceptionIO);
        }
    }

    public void flush() {
        try {
            this.outputIO.flush();
        } catch (IOException exceptionIO) {
            logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Can't flush Output Stream from Socket.", exceptionIO);
        }
    }

    protected OutputStream getOutputIO() {
        return this.outputIO;
    }


}
```

ProxMox.class (Example):

```
package de.bytestore.mytriox.proxmox;



public class ProxMox extends Module {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        WebClient clientIO = new WebClient(new URL("https://www.byte-store.de/index.html"));


        // host1.byte-system.de:8006
        WebHeader headerIO = clientIO.request();

        System.out.println(headerIO.getBody());
    }
     

}
```

WebClient.class
Plese look Pastebin, because i am limited in Chars.

[Pastebin  Link](https://pastebin.com/D9aeb5BQ)

Comment: Please, could you post the code used to send the header?

Comment: Simple output.....write(code.getBytes());....                                                                  
                    GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xxx.dear 
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Accept-Language: en-us

Comment: I ment to add it to your question. Questions about not working code without posting the code itself are not properly formed questions, and will sure get negative voting. But what is even more important, is that you won't easily get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I can't post my entire Code, because I am limited to some thousand Chars.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that following Code only works for HTTP:

```
            this.threadIO = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //while (!socketIO.isClosed() && readerIO.read() != -1) {
                    while (socketIO.isConnected() && !socketIO.isClosed()) {

                        // Byte Buffer ho contains read Data.
                        byte[] bufferIO = new byte[inputIO.available()];

                        // Read Data into Buffer and store (EOF).
                        int codeIO = inputIO.read(bufferIO);

                        //if (bufferIO.length != 0 && inputIO.available() == 0) {
                        if (bufferIO.length != 0 && inputIO.available() == 0) {

                            if (binaryIO)
                                binary(socketIO, bufferIO);

                            if (stringIO)
                                string(socketIO, new String(bufferIO, charsetIO));

                            if (hasCallbacks()) {
                                String dataIO = new String(bufferIO);

                                for (String keyIO : callbacksIO.keySet()) {
                                    if (dataIO.contains(keyIO)) {

                                        logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Executing Callback for Initiator '" + keyIO + "'.");

                                        callbacksIO.get(keyIO).string(socketIO, dataIO);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Sleep for 100 Milliseconds (CPU Usage)
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }

                    inputIO.reset();
                    inputIO.close();

                    if (!socketIO.isClosed()) {
                        socketIO.close();
                    }

                    disconnected(socketIO);

                    threadIO.stop();
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException errorIO) {
                    if (errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Stream closed.") || errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Connection reset")) {
                        logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Client was disconnected from Server with Address " + networkIO.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on Port " + networkIO.getPort() + ".");

                        disconnected(socketIO);
                    } else logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Socket throw an Error ", errorIO);
                }
            }
        });
```

But this works for HTTPS:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                BufferedReader readerIO = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(handshakeIO.getSocket().getInputStream()));

                                System.out.println("AAA");

                                String lineIO = null;
                                while ((lineIO = readerIO.readLine()) != null) {
                                    System.out.println(readerIO.readLine());
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Don't know why, but i think something is hanging my functions.